# Installing SIP and PyQt3

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, python-sip

I want to install PyQt3 because pip gives me an error I tried to install it manually. First I need to install sip (to get sipconfig module) when I tried make I get error:

```
siplib.c: In function ‘raiseNoWChar’:
siplib.c:10816: error: ‘PyExc_SystemError’ undeclared (first use in this function)
siplib.c: At top level:
siplib.c:10825: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
siplib.c:10858: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
make[1]: *** [siplib.o] Chyba 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/john/Python/sip-4.12.1/siplib'
make: *** [all] Chyba 2
```

I have Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it, I had to install python3-dev.